# How to set delay OnStepcomplete with dotween Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, dotween

I want to set a delay after every dotween loop. Onstepcomplete method doesn't seem to work with Ienumorator and SetDelay method delay at the start of the Tween. How do I it?

```
 void Movement()
{
    transform.DOPath(path, moveduration, pathType, pathMode, 10).SetLoops(-1, LoopType.Yoyo).SetEase(ease).SetDelay(startdelay)
        .OnStepComplete(StartCoroutine(Wait()));
}

private IEnumerator Wait()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer with a sample code that I tested (I tried a lot of combinations and this one worked, while the others not, I don't know why)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your tween in a sequence to do what you want.

```
DOTween.Sequence().SetDelay(1f).Append(transform.DOPath(XXX).OnComplete(XXX)).AppendInterval(1f).SetLoops(-1, LoopType.Yoyo).Play();
```